# Detail about saml onelogin logout

Tags: session, saml, logout, onelogin

I'm new to saml. I used onelogin and keycloack with the flask demo and now I'm trying to write a tornado demo. My question is: with flask demo, with 2 SP (I tried the flask demo on 2 different port) when a user logout on a single SP I noticed that the user logout also on the other SP (in the same realm). Is this the default saml behavior? (because I prefer have a specific logout for each application).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There's a couple of sessions in play here. Sessions with each SP. Session with Onelogin. Onelogin ( and SAML ) does support SLO ( Single Logout ) but you have to specifically configure it, and support it, in each application. If you haven't explicitly supported SLO then I'd suggest that your local logout is being applied to both SPs through killing the cookie that is handling your sessions on the client.